# composer update - doesn't get the newest version

Tags: git, github, composer-php, codeception

I would like to install the newest Codeception. According to the docs the latest stable version is 2.1.2

However when I put in my composer.json:

```
"codeception/codeception": "*",
```

I'm getting commit `b5af3aac061ffaeb65ed023534b3c50558e90d07` which is really old and doesn't have some issues fixes.

The question is - why composer doesn't take the latest changes from [2.1 branch](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commits/2.1) and what to do to force it to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is - why composer doesn't take the latest changes from 2.1 branch and what to do to force it to do it?

You are requiring a tag.

There is a difference between tags (2.1.2 / 2.1.0) and branches (2.1). The tags are static, while the branches are dynamic, still getting things on top.

When using `*` Composer will figure out the highest/latest tag version and use it and thats [2.1.2](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/tree/2.1.2) with [521adbb2](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commit/521adbb2ee34e9debdd8508a2c41ab2b5c2f042b). If you specify `2.1`, it would resolve to tag `2.1.0` with ref `b5af3aac061ffa`.

So, you might change from requiring tags to using branches instead:

`"codeception/codeception": "2.1.x-dev"` will fetch commit "c52a7384a7f60" from branch "2.1".

Please be aware that this is a moving target - a development branch.
And it should probably be a development dependency(, but that depends on the project).

---

`composer.json`

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "2.1.x-dev"
    }
}
```

`composer install`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will look it in details later, but why composer for `*` or `2.1.*` doesn't get latest commit from 2.1 branch - https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commits/2.1 ?

Comment: Because it resolves the version to a tag and not to a branch. `* ` = latest tag = 2.1.2

Comment: It seems the exact reason was other composer dependency in composer.json: `"facebook/webdriver": "~0.5"` which caused 2.1 version of codeception was taken instead of 2.1.2. When I changed it to `"facebook/webdriver": "1.*"` I got latest commit from 2.1.2 tag from https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commits/2.1.2